# Invalid Argument error in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs

My Javascript code goes something like this

```
Var Mainurl=”http://localhost/Employee/SearchEmployee.aspx?”
var url = { "eid" :empID, 
"DOB" : dob,
 "Gender" : gender,
 "Category" : category, 
"IsActive" :isActive 
};
window.open(Mainurl + Ext.urlEncode(url), 'Search Employee', "status=0, toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, resizable=1, scrollbars=0,height=700, width=1000" );
```

When I execute my application in IE (v6.0) it gives error “invalid arguments”  at window.open but  works fine in Firefox. 
Anyone has any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: The quotes you have in the first line (`”`) don't seem to be the standard `"` ones. Perhaps this is the cause of the problem. Are you pasting this from somewhere?

Comment: There might be script error in firefox too. But it might be suppressed. Please check.

Answer (score 3):

Change your first line from:

```
Var Mainurl=”http://localhost/Employee/SearchEmployee.aspx?”
```

To

```
var Mainurl="http://localhost/Employee/SearchEmployee.aspx?";
```

`Var` should be `var` and your speach marks should be `"` instead of `”`.

Answer (score 2):

Please correct the syntaxes first. 
Like `Var` should be `var`
Try the following url.

```
var url = { eid :empID, 
 DOB : dob,
 Gender : gender,
 Category : category, 
IsActive :isActive 
};
```

`Ext.urlEncode()` takes an object and converts it to an encoded URL. e.g. `Ext.urlEncode({foo: 1, bar: 2});` would return `"foo=1&bar=2"`. ..

Answer (score 1):

very surprised that such thing works in FF. you should use

```
var mainurl...
```

and NOT

```
Var Mainurl...
```

var is always var (lowercase). and variables like mainurl are lowercase too (but this is "just" convention).

so first change the Var to a var. and check if Ext.urlEncode is loaded and compatible with ie6 (don't know, but think its an js lib, right?).

and then get yourself a update on IE ;) (shouldnt support IE 6 anymore, way to much headache)